# Hyperlinks failing each time users download the excel from Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink

When editing the excel file the hyperlinks are working fine. But as soon as the excel is donwloaded the hyperlinks are corrupted and dont work anymore.

why this could happen?

thanks, as I am desperated trying to find a solution

Comment: where do the hyperlinks point to? are they sharepoint links to other files?

Answer (score 0):

I need to collect more information to further troubleshoot the issue:

Where is the hyperlinks exists?

Where do the hyperlinks point to?

What is the error message when you open the corrupted hyperlinks?

Please offer a screenshot about it.